# What is the link to a workflow of a Library

Tags: 2007, workflow

I have multiple workflows attached to a Library.

May I know what is the link to each workflow so that I can create a javascript button that will popup a window displaying the specific workflow?

The reason for asking is because suppose I have a website called `teamsites.mysite.com/collections/subsite`.

There is a workflow called `RemindFBUsersAdhoc` that allow user to manual start the workflow.

Therefore, the link will look something like the following:

`http://teamsites.mysite.com/collections/subsite/Workflows/RemindFBUsersAdhoc/RemindFBUsersAdhoc.aspx?List={LIST_Number}&ID={ID_Number}&TemplateID={WORKFLOW_Number}&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fteamsites%2Emysite%2Ecom%2Fcollections%2Fsubsite%2FForm%5FFBUsers%5FAdhoc%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx`

However, the problem is that everytime, I change my workflow `RemindFBUsersAdhoc` and publish again, the `TemplateID` will change. Then I will need to change my code again to set it to the correct Template ID, which I believe is the workflow ID for `RemindFBUsersAdhoc`.

The rest of the parameter did not give me much problem.

I was just wondering if the link that I used is correctly and I hope to remove such dynamic parameter like the `TemplateID`. So, are there really such link structure?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know 'Where are workflows stored?'

Workflows are stored in a site-level document library called Workflows. This document library is created automatically by Office SharePoint Designer 2007. In the Folder List, the Workflows document library displays the workflow icon instead of the usual list or document library icon. By default, the Workflows document library is hidden from the browser and has no List Views, such as AllItems.aspx or EditForm.aspx. This document library contains a folder for each workflow created with Office SharePoint Designer 2007

[More](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010100587.aspx#BM4)

Comment: Thanks SPGeek, I have update my question to make it more clearer. Yes, you can assume that I know where the workflows are stored and I know that there is a link to start the workflow manually but was wondering if I can make the link (the link that display the page where I can start the workflow manually) more static as I do not like to keep on changing the TemplateID everytime that I re-publish the workflow. Thanks.